# How can I set if statement inside map react?

Tags: react-native

I want to check if the agent social URL exists or not. I get the data via API and in the render I check if it is loaded and try to return the data for this section, but got stuck at this.

```js
if (isLoaded) {
  return (
    <section className="site-section" id="agents-section">
      <div className="container">

        <div className="row">

          {agent.map(agent =>

            <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
              <div className="team-member">
                <figure>
                  <ul className="social">
                    <li><a href={agent.facebook_url}><span className="icon-facebook" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href={agent.twitter_url}><span className="icon-twitter" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href={agent.linkedin_url}><span className="icon-linkedin" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href={agent.instagram_url}><span className="icon-instagram" /></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <img src={agent.agent_photo} alt="Image" className="img-fluid" />
                </figure>
                <div className="p-3 bg-primary">
                  <h3 className="mb-2">{agent.agent_name}</h3>
                  <span className="position">{agent.agent_position}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator `?:` as shown in below code.

```js
{
  agent.facebook_ur && agent.twitter_url && agent.linkedin_url && agent.instagram_url ?
    <figure>
      <ul className="social">
        <li><a href={agent.facebook_url}><span className="icon-facebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href={agent.twitter_url}><span className="icon-twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href={agent.linkedin_url}><span className="icon-linkedin" /></a></li>
        <li><a href={agent.instagram_url}><span className="icon-instagram" /></a></li>
      </ul>
      <img src={agent.agent_photo} alt="Image" className="img-fluid" />
    </figure>
    : null
}
```